# Долгое выполнение кода или бесконечный цикл?

Tags: c, производительность

Есть 2 списка, которые хранят в себе цифры числа. 
Ну и необходимо найти НОД этих чисел.
Если брать числа 9239923923999 - 99992399 - всё вроде как окей, работает. 
Если же 99999999999999 и 9, то просто жду..
Как понять, у меня где-то бесконечный цикл,  или сам код криво написан и поэтому долго считается?? Если 2-й вариант, каким образом ускорить??
Алгоритм НОД взял такой:

```
{
   while (a != b) {
        if (a > b) {
            long tmp = a;
            a = b;
            b = tmp;
        }
        b = b - a;
    }
    return a; 
    }
```

Т.к сделать вычитание двух чисел хранящихся в списке проще чем деление по модулю..
Собственно само вычитание:

```
{

    Item * tempfirst = A->Head;
    Item * tempsecond = B->Head;
    while (tempfirst && tempsecond)
    {
        if (tempfirst->digit < tempsecond->digit)
        {
            Item * CurrentItem = tempfirst;
            CurrentItem->digit += 10;
            CurrentItem = CurrentItem->next;
            while (CurrentItem->digit <= 0) 
            {
                CurrentItem->digit += 9;
                CurrentItem = CurrentItem->next;
            }
            CurrentItem->digit -= 1;
        }
        tempfirst->digit -= tempsecond->digit;
        tempfirst = tempfirst->next;
        tempsecond = tempsecond->next;
    }
        tempfirst = A->Tail;
        while (tempfirst) 
        {
            if (tempfirst->digit != 0)
                break;
            A->Tail = tempfirst->prev;
            A->Tail->next = NULL;
            free(tempfirst); 
            tempfirst = A->Tail; 
            A->size--;
        }
        return A;
    }

}
```

В остальном, вроде как уверен.. 
Но чувствую в вычитании где-то то-ли ошибка, то ли еще что.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вы даете... Так можно до морковкина заговенья считать НОД...

Понятно, что считать нужно через остаток! Ведь прикиньте - даже если просто из 99999999999999 вычитать по 9 - обычной арифметикой, пусть за наносекунду - то потребуется 10^13 наносекунд, или 10000 секунд - часа 3. А у вас, с вашей сложной процедурой?!

Comment: у меня Си. Шаблоны нельзя..

Comment: Да дело не в шаблоне. Для `m` и `n` НОД считается как `while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n; return m + n;`. Реализуйте операцию получения остатка, иначе толку не будет.

Comment: Эх.. Ну, я в принципе предполагал что оно долго будет считать, но всё же больше надеялся что где-то накосячил и словил бесконечный цикл.

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, извините, что огорчил... Если ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ, как принятый...

Comment: Про то что вопросы можно закрыть - не знал. Сейчас закрою.

Comment: А можете идейно подсказать, как реализовать деление с остатком? Что для этого нужно? Я так понимаю, что мне нужно немного изменить структуру списка. К примеру число 123. 1 - начало. 3- конец. Ибо сейчас у меня 3-начало 1 - конец. Что для этого надо? 
Например: есть 2 числа, x и y; x > y;
Брать i = 1; Умножать на y, пока не будет больше x .(к примеру i = 7 к этому моменту) Откатываю i назад на i = 6, 
Умножаю y на 6, от x отнимаю y. 
Поправьте, если можно лучше, ибо не хочется второй раз засыпаться..

Answer (score 0):

[Алгоритм Евклида для нахождения наибольшего общего делителя (НОД)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0), записанный с помощью деления с остатком:

```
U gcd(U a, U b)
{
  while (b) {
    U t = b;
    b = a % b;
    a = t;
  }
  return a;
}
```

где `U`: `typedef unsigned long U;`

Если эффективная реализация `a % b` не доступна, то можно попробовать алгоритм, который использует [`x >> 1` (сдвиг вправо)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3) и `x & 1` (чётный/нечётный) [побитовые операции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8):

```
U gcd(U a, U b)
{
  if (a == b)
    return a;
  if (a == 0)
    return b;
  if (b == 0)
    return a;
  // a != b and > 0
  if (a & 1) { // a is odd
    if (b & 1) {// b is odd
      // both odd, diff is even, reduce larger arg
      return (a > b) ? gcd((a - b) >> 1, b) : gcd((b - a) >> 1, a);
    } else { // a is odd, b is even
      return gcd(a, b >> 1);
    }
  } else if (b & 1) { // a is even, b is odd
    return gcd(a >> 1, b);
  }
  // a is even, b is even
  return gcd(a >> 1, b >> 1) << 1; // non tail-recursive
}
```

Пример использования:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("%lu\n", gcd(99999999999999, 9));
  return 0;
}
```

Пример запуска:

```
$ cc *.c && time ./a.out
9
./a.out  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
```

Видно, что код мгновенно выполняется.

Comment: Алгоритмов то много. На codelive целых 8 штук. Тот который я брал - так же в списке. Скорость выполнения там была тоже хорошая, но, увы, "Доверяй но проверяй" - не про меня.
А данный алгоритм я разобрать не смог, к сожалению.. 
Да и в любом случае придется реализовать операции >> и &
Я так понимаю что >> 1, разделить на два. 
Потому наверное будет проще сразу определять операцию деления с остатком.
Если конкретнее подскажите, как ее реализовать - буду благодарен. (свой вариант я оставил под ответом выше в комментарии)

Comment: @TorSen разница между `x>>1` (shr) и `x%y` (div) может быть большой. Не смотря на более сложный алгоритм, [вариант со сдвигом (Stein) в среднем  до 60% быстрее в терминах побитовых операций алгоритма Евклида](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) — ваш вопрос имеет метку производительность — поэтому приведение такого алгоритма совершенно уместно. Хотя на практике, многие современные процессоры имеют эффективную инструкцию деления (не ваш  случай, насколько я понял), поэтому без измерений, сложно сказать какой из представленных вариантов, на каких данных и железе будет быстрее.

Comment: >>поэтому приведение такого алгоритма совершенно уместно.

так никто и не спорит. Дело в том, что вариант с побитовыми, в присутствии с рекурсией для опытных людей, новичкам(по крайне мере мне) они трудны для понимания. А если еще и учесть тот факт, что нужно это всё делать используя списки - так тем более.

Comment: @TorSen Если не получается логический сдвиг на единицу реализовать для вашего представления, то  задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом. Явно опишите как у вас числа представлены. Проверка на чётность ещё проще реализуется. Для этого понимания алгоритма/рекурсии не требуется, хотя со временем вы поймёте что это простой алгоритм (и рекурсию полезно понимать, но не всё сразу). Если что-то не ясно — спрашивайте.

Comment: Всё-таки остановился на варианте с делением с остатком. (ибо остаток его я обосновать смогу, а до таких алгоритмов, я еще не дорос.) 
По поводу алгоритма: 
Откуда берется четность \ нечетность числа и за счет чего - понятно. Что делают побитовые сдвиги и для чего - не ясно.